# o campo é muito pequeno para aceitar a quantidade de dados que você tentou adicionar. Tente inserir ou colar menos dados

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-access

Estou usando o Acess, e já verifiquei o tamanho de todos campos e formato também direto do banco e também no próprio vb.net.

```
"insert into aplicacao (codigo, convenio, descricao , valconv, ativo, usuario, maquina, data_registro, flag)
VALUES
(@codigo, @convenio, @descricao , @valconv, @ativo, @usuario, @maquina, @data_registro, @flag)"
```

Answer (score 0):

esse campo código é auto incremento?
Caso seja, não se faz necessário inputalo no insert.
Se não for isso, possivelmente esteja passando um valor de 255 caracteres para um campo no access q só tem 100 caracteres.
Abs